# set cookie using jquery, bodyclass from cookie on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies, document-body

I have a button which sets body class to .blackout

I'm using [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)
to set the cookie, and the following code is associated with my button.

```
<script>
$('#boToggle').on('click', function(e) {
  $('body').toggleClass('blackout'); 
});
</script>
```

What I can't figure out is how to use `Cookies.set('name', 'value');` from the link above to set the cookie with the .toggleClass AND how to retrieve it from cookie and apply it to body class.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What cookie `key` and `value` do you want to set?

Comment: You may be using Cookies inappropriately but setting and getting a cookie using js-cookie is pretty straight forward. You'll likely want to stringify your data then parse it on the way out.

Comment: `.toggleClass('blackout', Cookies.get('name') == 'value')` perhaps? I'm not sure I understand the problem though

Comment: d'oh. I copied the wrong code! how embarrassing.

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so you should accept an answer or give additional feedback

Comment: Jeanpier - yes it did! Sorry I have been away! Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to maintain the state of your toggled class between sessions which could be done with Cookies but would perhaps be better suited for localStorage.

For the sake of completeness I'll demonstrate both approaches

**With Cookies**

To better understand the distinction between Cookies and Local Storage see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies), but I honestly think you could go with either approach. One advantage Local Storage has over cookies in this case is that you wouldn't need an additional library.

```
let state = Cookies.get('toggle');
$(body).toggleClass('.blackout', state)
```

**With Local Storage**

```
let state = localStorage.getItem('toggle');
$(body).toggleClass('.blackout', state)
```

**With your updated snippet**

```
var toggleLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('toggle');
var toggleStatus = toggleLocalStorage ? toggleLocalStorage : false;

$('#boToggle').on('click', function(e) {
  $('body').toggleClass('blackout', toggleStatus);
  localStorage.setItem('toggle' toggleStatus);
});
```

Comment: Hmm! I've never tried local storage before now. And I couldn't seem to get it to work. My updated code is above for the toggle button (which I copied the wrong snippet... that was my junk code lol)

Comment: Depends you'll need an event/action for `Cookie.set` or `localStorage.setItem`. The mechanism works the same, you could have it save on every click in which case you'd include the snippet I shared inside of your on 'click' handler. @SaraHubrich I've added a more concrete example for you to try.